# Accuracy testing a word2vec model using COSADD, COSMUL and euclidean distance

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I have trained a model in word2vec and want to use googles analogy test set to test its accuracy. I want to use COSADD, COSMUL and hopefully euclidean distance.

To use COSADD i simply use the code:
model.wv.accuracy(‘questions-words.txt’).

I’m not sure how to use the others. The accuracy method has the following optional parameters
accuracy(.txt file, restrict_vocab=..., most_similar=...)

where I feel like I should be able to write most_similar = COSMUL

but this does not work :(

Does anyone know how to do the accuracy test with COSMUL or euclidean distance (or both)?

Answer (score 0):

The `most_similar` parameter of `accuracy()` takes a python function, so you'd need to provide a function, with the same method-signature as [`KeyedVectors.most_similar()`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/a6c4ea4fc625174dd9fb12d739b20fe400edd3d6/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L475), that performs your alternate calculation.

Something like [`WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.most_similar_cosmul()`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/a6c4ea4fc625174dd9fb12d739b20fe400edd3d6/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L804) may work for cosmul calculation.

You should, however, review the source code tosee what's expected, and how certain default choices in the code (like whether the unit-normalize word-vectors) will affect your result.

Comment: I'm struggling with writing an acceptable function... even if i write most_similar=most_similar as they docs say is the default parameter, i get this error:
NameError: name 'most_similar' is not defined.

When I try to write KeyedVectors.most_similar_cosmul(), I get the same error.

Comment: The source code can use `most_similar` because it is a defined function name in that context. If you wanted to specify the same function from your own code module, you'd have to specify `WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.most_similar`. Also, note in my answer above I suggest `WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.most_similar_cosmul()` for this same reason: that's the full name of of the function, if you've imported `WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors`. It's not defined on `KeyedVectors` itself.

Comment: Ok thank you, I have no imported WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors with from gensim.models.keyedvectors import WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors. My code now gives me this error: most_similar_cosmul() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're supplying just the function object, *don't* use `()` parentheses - that means to "execute the function", in which case you'd need to supply all necessary arguments, and then the `accuracy()` method is receiving the *results* of that execution, not the function itself. Try as the parameter: `most_similar= WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.most_similar_cosmul`.

Comment: The error now says:   File "C:\Users\Nell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 1419, in new_func1
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 1218, in accuracy
    sims = most_similar(self, positive=[b, c], negative=[a], topn=False, restrict_vocab=restrict_vocab)
TypeError: most_similar_cosmul() got an unexpected keyword argument 'restrict_vocab'.

Comment: I have now made it work by overriding the most_similar_cosmul method to include the restrict_vocab parameter. Thank you so much for your help, really appreciate it.